# JQuery. Плагины. Делегированная установка

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру есть некий плагин *plaginName*. Он устанавливается на элементы :

```
$('.plaginName-elms').plaginName();
```

А как сделать так, что бы это сработало и для еще не существующих элементов? Что то на подобии :

```
$('body').on('click', '.elms', function() {
    console.log('success');
});
```

Comment: как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: @Grundy, ну, даже не знаю. Ведь как-то изначально устанавливаются "обработчики" плагином. Почему тогда делегировано не возможно сделать это? Или не возможно все-таки?

Comment: Потому что обработчики срабатывают один раз на контейнере и дальше простым ифом проверяется источник. В случае же инициализации, нужно отслеживать _все добавления_ в DOM что может быть довольно накладно и **вызывать** инит для добавленного элемента

Comment: @Grundy, ясно, жаль... спасибо!

Comment: но это не невозможно:)

Comment: @Grundy, ну если бы еще не накладно было :)

Comment: все зависит от плагина: тот же тултип вполне себе применяется ко всем вложенным и динамическим элементам, если инициализирован на документе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теоретически, с помощью [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) можно следить за DOM, в случае появления новых нужных элементов, запускать плагин для них.
Но это не очень кроссбраузерно пока что и никто так не делает.

Гораздо проще чуть лучше контролировать свой контент.

Например у вас есть функция `addNewItem()`, которая добавляет новый элемент в DOM. Ничто не мешает внутри этой функции каждый раз вызывать инициализацию плагина для вновь созданного элемента.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте всплытие событий. Как-то так например

```
$('body').click(function(e){
 var elem = $(e.target).closest('.plaginName-elms');
 if (elem.length==0) return;
 elem.plaginName();
});
```

Comment: а если инициализация нужна автоматическая после добавления элемента, а не по клику?

Comment: Да, нужна именно автоматическая инициализация

Comment: Генерируйте событие при добавлении
`$('<div>').addClass('plaginName-elms').appendTo($('body')).trigger('click');`